# 2002 Civic not starting when cold in GA tmeps 40's

Tags: honda, battery, starting, civic

So, I am having the same problem but in GA, USA.  My car will not start when it's cold and I'm not talking negative's.  This just started a couple of weeks ago when the temps dropped below 40 degree F and again this morning it was 44 degree F.  Quick history about the car; she is just over 166K and appx. 161K I rebuilt her [NEW head gasket, water pump, tensioner, all belts, upper oxygen sensor, air intake sensor, and a couple of other i can't remember].  Replaced battery just before rebuilt [May 2018], so when it started acting up 3 weeks ago, it was like WTF.  Replaced the main 80amp fuse, New spark plugs still nothing.  Checked the starter, works fine.  I finally decided to check the battery after appx. 25+ cranks, the voltage was at 12.3.  Charged the battery and that started the car but it was also warm that afternoon.  She ran fine, drove appx. 10 miles 3 times that day.  Guess what happened the next morning, nothing; turns over but does not crank up.  Pulled the battery and took it to advance auto for exchange, they didn't test it but they did give me a new battery.   Put the NEW battery in Nov 22nd in the afternoon, temp in the 70's abd if course she cranks up.  Left on VACA for Thanksgiving and came back on Nov. 30 late evening temps in the 60's and of course she cranks; used the car 2x on sunday with no problem. This morning Dec. 2nd temps are in the 40's, and of course the car will not turn over.  Also, all fluids are good.  I will try to crank the car up when i get home today, temps should be close to 60 degreese.  Tomorrow it will be in the 30's, if it does not crank, i will try warming up the battery with a hiar dryer to see if this helps.
So, for the past couple of days when i get home i can crank the car just fine; temps are in the 60.  Drove the car to ADV Auto where the checked the battery and it tested just fine, no problems.  Here's what i did last night, disconnected the battery, brought it inside.  This morning i connected the battery and the car started just fine, it was 37 degrees this morning.  Has anyone tried that or put a heating pad and warming the battery first?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If I am understanding you correctly, the car will crank (engine rotates) but will not start (run) when this behavior is exhibiting itself? Is there any issue at all with the engine rotating (by the starter) during this time? Does it sound like the engine rotation is bogging (not spinning very fast)? Does the engine sound like it wants to start at all?

Comment: 40s are cold? That word, I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @GdD - Ask someone in Saudi Arabia or the Amazon Jungle if 40°F is cold ... it's all in one's perspective.